# Android Sqlite multi threading save data with DBFlow + Retrofit

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, retrofit2, dbflow

I'm using DBFlow to save into the database and Retrofit to call my web service. My retrofit class is the same class as my Database table. But I have a problem when 2 threads or more are launched at the same time to save my data into the table. The insert into my table duplicate my data and the primary key is duplicated too. Then my thread is stopped because it crashes.

Have you a solution for that ?

**Class for Retrofit and DBFlow**

```
@Table(database = LocalDB.class)
@Root(name = "picture_infos")
public class PictureInfos extends BaseModel {

@PrimaryKey
@Element(name = "id_picture")
private int idPicture;

@Column
@Element(name = "id_account")
private String idAccount;

@Column
@Element(name = "folder_path")
private String folderPath;

@Column
@Element(name = "filename")
private String filename;

@Column
@Element(name = "legend", required = false)
private String legend;

public int getIdPicture() {
    return idPicture;
}

public void setIdPicture(int idPicture) {
    this.idPicture = idPicture;
}

public String getIdAccount() {
    return idAccount;
}

public void setIdAccount(String idAccount) {
    this.idAccount = idAccount;
}

public String getFolderPath() {
    return folderPath;
}

public void setFolderPath(String folderPath) {
    this.folderPath = folderPath;
}

public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}

public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public String getLegend() {
    return legend;
}

public void setLegend(String legend) {
    this.legend = legend;
}
}
```

**Thread in retrofit response**

```
public void onResponse(Call<AdminPictures> call, Response<AdminPictures> response) {
            AdminPictures apResponse = response.body();
            final List<PictureInfos> pictureInfos = apResponse.getPicturesList();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            for (PictureInfos infos : pictureInfos) {
                    // This save duplicate when I've 2 or more threads
                              synchronized (infos){
                                if(!infos.exists()){
                                   infos.save();
                                 }
                              }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

**Stacktrace**

```
    03-18 12:01:18.950 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin E/SQLiteLog: (1555) abort at 12 in [INSERT INTO `PictureInfos`(`idPicture`,`idAccount`,`folderPath`,`filename`,`legend`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: PictureInfos.idPicture
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: PictureInfos.idPicture (code 1555)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:788)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.database.AndroidDatabaseStatement.executeInsert(AndroidDatabaseStatement.java:77)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.SqlUtils.insert(SqlUtils.java:370)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.SqlUtils.save(SqlUtils.java:327)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.ModelAdapter.save(ModelAdapter.java:60)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.BaseModel.save(BaseModel.java:52)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin.GalleryActivity$1$1.run(GalleryActivity.java:188)
    03-18 12:01:18.951 15696-19086/com.vigizen.client.kiosqueadmin W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: `Synchronize` the method using save call, so that only one thread is updating in to the database at a time

Comment: I think the attributes that can be accessed in several threads at a time should be volatile to prevent concurrent write/read ? (I'm not specialist but that makes sens to me) EDIT : @ViswanathLekshmanan response is better I think

Comment: I've try volatile members but there is no changes. @ViswanathLekshmanan I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is the first "dont' do" in the [docs of DBFlow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage2/StoringData.md). What you should use here is a transaction to store the data. This locks the database for an exclusive batch operation and should be a lot faster than iterating over all you models and save them one by one.

Basically, you want to use `FastStoreModelTransaction.saveBuilder()` here which basically does a `INSERT OR UPDATE`.

Usage would be like that:

```
public void onResponse(Call<AdminPictures> call, Response<AdminPictures> response) {
    AdminPictures apResponse = response.body();
    final List<PictureInfos> pictureInfos = apResponse.getPicturesList();

    FastStoreModelTransaction transaction = FastStoreModelTransaction.saveBuilder(FlowManager.getModelAdapter(PictureInfos.class))
        .addAll(pictureInfos)
        .build();

    database.executeTransaction(transaction);
}
```

Please note that this would automatically runs in the background, so no need to wrap it in an extra thread. If you need a listener on the storing process, use the `ProcessModelTransaction` instead.

Answer (score -2):

Reading database can be done in parallel without interrupting each other, but writing in to database should be done in a synchronized way if you have keys.

You should write the `save` within a synchronized method. Synchronize will allow only one thread to do changes at a time.

**Note:**
By default android `SQLiteDatabase` Object is safe for multithreading. `DBFlow` is also. Make sure you are using the same instances of helpers in multiple threads.

[Details](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm)

Comment: Ok thanks I don't know the synchronized. I tried your method but I think I do a mistake.                    `synchronized (infos){
                                        if (!infos.exists()) {
                                            infos.save();
                                        }
                                    }`

Comment: @John Primary key should not get duplicated in database at any cost. That is a real issue. Log the execution including the keys and please post before you synchronize it

Comment: When I execute the thread after the first was end, I don't have the primary key issue. I have the good value for each primary key. The problem comes when I launch 2 threads in same time and I have this error E/SQLiteLog: (1555) abort at 12 in [INSERT INTO `PictureInfos`(`idPicture`,`idAccount`,`folderPath`,`filename`,`legend`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: PictureInfos.idPicture

Comment: How same primary key is assigned to both objects ? That is  not a multithread issue . How you are creating objects to insert ? Show the whole code including creation and execution

Comment: I don't know why but the problem comes when this thread is called twice

Comment: there is the whole code here. Retrofit fill my object during the data parsing. And with the .save() of DBFlow I insert my data. Maybe Retrofit + DBFlow doesn't work ? Or I should create one class for Retrofit and one class for DBflow ?

Comment: No thats fine. Check how many times you send request. Log that as well. Issue may be requesting same multiple times

Comment: First retrofit call : 265 insert in the database and second call 303 insert. And when I call them at the same time, there is the crash so the thread is done.

Comment: please post the stacktrace of the crash

Comment: Maybe this line ` final List<PictureInfos> pictureInfos = apResponse.getPicturesList();` can be a problem ? Because this variable is final ?

Comment: Absolutely you are correct. Since you have 2 different primary key, you dont have the uniques constraint exception. remove the final one or create different instance of interfaces

Comment: Stacktrace in my question

Comment: Saw that, If you log the primary key just above the save call , you will get the same value for both. Its because of the final List

Comment: Ok I'll try to make a private variable instead of final

Comment: No that will not make any difference.

Comment: You are requesting multiple times using same interface. Use a different instance

Comment: I don't know how I can do that if I can't use final or a private member. And I can't send a parameter to the run function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106712/discussion-between-john-and-viswanath-lekshmanan).

Comment: I tried to set 2 different list in two threads. And I don't know why my list are mixed ... see thread n°1 : 3068
thread n°1 : 3067
thread n°1 : 3066
thread n°2 : 3068
thread n°2 : 3067
thread n°2 : 3066

Comment: There is no threading issue in this. Only mistake on some part. You just debug the execution step by step after receiving the request